# Button in a modal populated via JS not works

Tags: javascript, laravel, bootstrap-modal

i've in my laravel 8 project a modal populated dynamically by clicking a row in a table, and in the footer of the modal i've an `<input type="submit">`.
But when I click on the button nothing happens, and I can't figure out if the problem is due to how I created the form or if I'm wrong in the code.
Anyone have any suggestions? Where am I wrong?

here my code:

```xml
<tbody>
    @foreach ($users as $u)
        <tr wire:click='openModal({{ $u->id }})'>
            <td>{{ $u->username }}</td>
            <td>{{ $u->nome }}</td>
            <td>{{ $u->cognome }}</td>
            <td>{{ $u->email }}</td>
            <td>{{ $u->codicefiscale }}</td>
            <td>{{ $u->ruolo == 0 ? 'Admin' : 'Collaboratore' }}</td>
            <td>
                <div class="d-flex">
                    <a href="{{ url('tenants/' . $idt . '/users/'.$u->id.'/update') }}" class="btn btn-primary shadow btn-xs sharp mr-1" >
                        <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
                    </a>
                    <form method="POST" action="{{ url('tenants/' . $idt . '/users/impersonate') }}">
                        @csrf
                        <input type="hidden" value="{{ $u->id }}" name="idu">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success shadow btn-xs sharp">
                            <i class="fa fa-user-circle-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </button>
                    </form>
                    <form method="POST" action="{{ url('tenants/' . $idt . '/users/delete') }}">
                        @csrf
                        @method('delete')
                        <input type="hidden" value="{{ $u->id }}" name="idu">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger shadow btn-xs sharp">
                            <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
                        </button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            <td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
</tbody>
<div class="modal fade" id="UtenteLongModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title">Dettagli dell'utente</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span>&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <!-- da aggiungere l'azione -->
                <div class="basic-form">
                    <!-- modal popolato dallo script -->
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    window.addEventListener('open', event => {
        var url = '{{ url("tenants/:idt/users/:idu/resetPassword") }}';
        url = url.replace(':idt', event.detail.idt);
        url = url.replace(':idu', event.detail.user.id);
        url = url.replace('%3Aidu', '');

        $(".modal-body").empty();
        $(".modal-body").append('<div class="form-group row"><label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Username</label><div class="col-sm-9"><input type="text" class="form-control input-rounded" readonly name="username" placeholder="'+event.detail.user.username+'" /></div></div>' );
        $(".modal-body").append('<div class="form-group row"><label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Nome</label><div class="col-sm-9"><input type="text" class="form-control input-rounded" readonly name="username" placeholder="'+event.detail.user.nome+'" /></div></div>' );
        $(".modal-body").append('<div class="form-group row"><label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Cognome</label><div class="col-sm-9"><input type="text" class="form-control input-rounded" readonly name="username" placeholder="'+event.detail.user.cognome+'" /></div></div>' );
        $(".modal-body").append('<div class="form-group row"><label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Email</label><div class="col-sm-9"><input type="text" class="form-control input-rounded" readonly name="username" placeholder="'+event.detail.user.email+'" /></div></div>' );
        $(".modal-body").append('<div class="form-group row"><label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Codice Fiscale</label><div class="col-sm-9"><input type="text" class="form-control input-rounded" readonly name="username" placeholder="'+event.detail.user.codicefiscale+'" /></div></div>' );
        $(".modal-body").append('<div class="form-group row"><label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Abilitato</label><div class="col-sm-9"><input type="text" class="form-control input-rounded" readonly name="username" placeholder="'+event.detail.user.abilitato+'" /></div></div>' );
        $(".modal-body").append('<div class="form-group row"><label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Qualifica</label><div class="col-sm-9"><input type="text" class="form-control input-rounded" readonly name="username" placeholder="'+event.detail.user.id_qualifica+'" /></div></div>' );
        $(".modal-body").append('<div class="form-group row"><label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Ruolo</label><div class="col-sm-9"><input type="text" class="form-control input-rounded" readonly name="username" placeholder="'+event.detail.user.ruolo+'" /></div></div>' );
        $(".modal-body").append('<div class="form-group row"><label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Ufficio</label><div class="col-sm-9"><input type="text" class="form-control input-rounded" readonly name="username" placeholder="'+event.detail.user.ufficio+'" /></div></div>' );
        $(".modal-body").append('<div class="form-group row"><label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Indirizzo</label><div class="col-sm-9"><input type="text" class="form-control input-rounded" readonly name="username" placeholder="'+event.detail.user.indirizzo+'" /></div></div>' );
        $(".modal-body").append('<div class="form-group row"><label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Comune</label><div class="col-sm-9"><input type="text" class="form-control input-rounded" readonly name="username" placeholder="'+event.detail.user.id_comune+'" /></div></div>' );
        $(".modal-body").append('<div class="form-group row"><label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Provincia</label><div class="col-sm-9"><input type="text" class="form-control input-rounded" readonly name="username" placeholder="'+event.detail.user.id_provincia+'" /></div></div>' );
        $(".modal-body").append('<div class="form-group row"><label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">CAP</label><div class="col-sm-9"><input type="text" class="form-control input-rounded" readonly name="username" placeholder="'+event.detail.user.cap+'" /></div></div>' );
        $(".modal-body").append('<div class="form-group row"><label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Cellulare</label><div class="col-sm-9"><input type="text" class="form-control input-rounded" readonly name="username" placeholder="'+event.detail.user.cellulare+'" /></div></div>' );
        $(".modal-body").append('<div class="form-group row"><label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Telefono</label><div class="col-sm-9"><input type="text" class="form-control input-rounded" readonly name="username" placeholder="'+event.detail.user.telefono+'" /></div></div>' );
        $(".modal-body").append('<div class="form-group row"><label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Fax</label><div class="col-sm-9"><input type="text" class="form-control input-rounded" readonly name="username" placeholder="'+event.detail.user.fax+'" /></div></div>' );
        // $(".modal-body").append('<div class="form-group row"><label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Scrittura</label><div class="col-sm-9"><input type="text" class="form-control input-rounded" readonly name="username" placeholder="'+event.detail.user.scrittura+'" /></div></div>' );
        $(".modal-footer").empty();
        $(".modal-footer").append('<form id="resetPasswordForm" method="POST" action="'+url+'">');
        $(".modal-footer").append('@csrf()');
        $(".modal-footer").append('<input type="text" hidden name="idu" value="'+event.detail.user.id+'"/>');
        $(".modal-footer").append('<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Resetta la password" />');
        $(".modal-footer").append('</form>');
        // document.getElementById("resetPasswordForm").submit();
        $("#UtenteLongModal").modal('show');
    })
</script>
```

I tested with `console.log(url)` if the generated url was correct and it is, and uncommenting `document.getElementById("resetPasswordForm").submit ();` in my script I go automatically (as it is correct to be) on the requested url with error 419.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are appending the input fields of the form outside of the actual form. That's why nothing will actually happen on a click action.

You have to append them like this (i'm using the user id to distinguish different forms from different modals when multiple users are on the table)

```
$(".modal-footer").append('<form id="resetPasswordForm' + event.detail.user.id + '" method="POST" action="'+url+'">');
$("#resetPasswordForm" + event.detail.user.id).append('@csrf()');
$("#resetPasswordForm" + event.detail.user.id).append('<input type="text" hidden name="idu" value="'+event.detail.user.id+'"/>');
$("#resetPasswordForm" + event.detail.user.id).append('<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Resetta la password" />');
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
$(".modal-footer").append('@csrf()');
```

Try

```
$(".modal-footer").append('{{ csrf_field() }}');
```

I'm not sure the blade directive is working as it should there.

Comment: Hi, i've tried but when i click the csrf_token() is displayed on the modal, but when i click the submit nothing happens